# Exercise on zeros of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have to find the order of $f (z)=\sinh z -z;$ then I must show that $f $ has infinite zeros, and that the zeros different from $0$ have order $1$.

The order of $f $ is $1$; however I don't know how to continue. There is a theorem stating that $\mathfrak n (r)\le Cr^\rho$, where $\mathfrak n (r)$ is the number of zeros in the disk $D_r (0)$, $\rho$ is the order of the function and $C $ is a constant. However this is not enough to say that the zeros are infinitely many. How can I proceed? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of $f$"?

Comment: @Arthur Presumably, the OP mean the order of an entire function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type

Comment: It has infinitely many zeros because it is not of the form $P(z) e^{az}$ with $P$ a polynomial ($P(z) e^{az}+z$ is not its own second derivative)

Comment: $g(z) = f(z)/z^3$ is even. $z \mapsto g(\sqrt{z})$ has order $1/2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry I don't understand the link between the function that you defined and $f $

Comment: @reuns Can you explain me where did you get your result from? did you refer to some theorem? I'm studying from Stein Shakarchi but I didn't see anything similar. Thank you

Comment: Except for $z = 0$, $g$ has the same zeros as $f$. The zeros of $h \colon z \mapsto g(\sqrt{z})$ are the squares of the zeros of $g$. An entire function of non-integral order always has infinitely many zeros, therefore $h$, and hence $g$, has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: reuns is using the fact that an entire function of order $1$ with only finitely many zeros can be written in the form $P(z)e^{az}$ with a polynomial $P$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. This follows from the Hadamard factorisation theorem, some form of which should appear in the book. Then it's a simple exercise that $P(z)e^{az} + z$ cannot satisfy the differential equation $y'' = y$ that $\sinh$ satisfies. (Well, simple if you know how.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $f$ has infinitely many zeros follows from the fact that $0$ is not a Picard exceptional value, i.e., that $f$ is not of the form $Pe^Q$ with polynomials $P$ and $Q$, but it can also be shown more directly using the argument principle, which even gives you a count of the zeros: If $R = [-2\pi k,2\pi k]^2$ denotes the square centered at zero, with side length $4\pi k$, where $k$ is a large positive integer, then by the argument principle the number of zeros of $f$ inside $R$, counted with multiplicity, is $N = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\partial R} d \arg f(z)$. Writing $z=x+iy$, on the right boundary of $R$ you have that $|\sinh z| \gg |z|$, so $\arg f(z) \approx \arg \sinh z \approx y$, so the argument of $f(z)$ changes by approximately $4\pi k$. Similarly, on the left boundary you have $\arg f(z) \approx -y$, so the argument also changes by approximately $4\pi k$. On the top boundary the argument changes by $\approx -\pi$, and the same is true on the bottom boundary. Taking everything together you get that $N \approx \frac{8\pi k -2\pi}{2\pi} = 4k-1$. Since this has to be an integer, it will be equal to $4k-1$ (for $k$ large enough), so that this is the number of zeros inside $R$.